# Post_list function in Rtweet package

Tags: r, rtweet

Is the post_list function in the rtweet package no longer in existence?

The documentation shows it as a function but I get the error message that the function doesn't exist when I try to use it?

I am trying to use a list of Twitter handles to create a list in Twitter, but can't find a function to make it work.

users <- c("cnn", "cnnbrk", "cnni", "cnnpolitics", "cnnmoney",
           "cnnnewsroom", "cnnspecreport", "CNNNewsource",
           "CNNNSdigital", "CNNTonight")

```
 ## create CNN-accounts list with 9 total users
 (cnn_lst <- post_list(users,
                  "cnn-accounts", description = "Official CNN 
 accounts"))

Message:
Error in post_list(users, "cnn-accounts", description = "Official CNN 
accounts") : 
could not find function "post_list"
```

Comment: can you add stack trace and version details of rtweet package you are using?

Comment: Most likely the reason behind your error would be spelling mistake or caps.

Comment: Hi @RishikeshJha, I've added the error message I get, when I type post too, I get a list of optional functions and post_list isn't there

Comment: I've found the issue! I was using an old version of the rtweet package, I've updated to the latest version and the issue is gone